# PHP transform array from one dimenson to two

Tags: php, arrays

some "simple" problem:

I've this array;

```
$myArray = array(
'FOO',
'BAR,
);
```

i want :

```
$mayArray = array(
   'FOO' => array(),
   'BAR' => array(),
);
```

in the moment iam doing it with an foreach:

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $val) {
    $newArray[$val] = array();
}

$myArray = $newArray;
```

is there an easyer way ? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you have is pretty easy to understand. But you can also do this:

```
 $myArray = array_fill_keys($myArray, array());
```

Docs here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php

Answer (score 4):

You can use [array_fill_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php), here is example:

```
$myArray = array_fill_keys($myArray, array());
```